# Is the $SHELL environment variable only for interactive shells?

Tags: shell, posix, exec

I see two possible uses for the `SHELL` environment variable:

- It can be used to specify the *interactive* shell the user wants to use, and/or
- it can be used by processes to execute other commands with, replacing the command in the usual `/bin/sh -c "..."` idiom.

If it were only used for the former, it could be something very weird (e.g. `ipython`), if it shall also be used for the latter, it needs to provide a basic form of POSIX compatibility, e.g. understand the `-c` parameter and keep the environment intact ([which is surprisingly tricky](http://www.mail-archive.com/dash@vger.kernel.org/msg01146.html)).

The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) is not very explicit here, it just writes.

> This variable shall represent a pathname of the user's preferred command language interpreter. If this interpreter does not conform to the Shell Command Language in the Shell and Utilities volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Chapter 2, Shell Command Language, utilities may behave differently from those described in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001.

Is the second use actually common and/or valid, and hence something to worry about if I set `SHELL` to something strange?

Comment: The question seems to assume that setting `SHELL` is mandatory: it is not.  POSIX merely states how the variable is interpreted when set.  As for "correct", that aspect makes the question opinion-based (it will only attract opinions).

Comment: @ThomasDickey I think the OP simply means _valid_ or _safe_. Joachim, I'm not too sure what you're asking though. You are including an example of `$SHELL` being used for your second point in th question already. What else do you need?

Comment: The first half of the question is the problem.  If it were only clarifying why `make` may use `SHELL`, that is straightforward.  But the paragraph beginning "If it were only used", etc., undermines the question.

Comment: gnu make does not use the environment variable SHELL (but it uses its own SHELL variable to get the shell to use if you set it).  Is there variance in that behavior? A lot of people around me are using tcsh and I think it would have broken our makefiles when we were not yet standardized on gnu make and were using the makes provided by Sun, HP and IBM.

Comment: @AProgrammer thanks for clarifying that. I got the information on make’s use of `SHELL` from someone else, who confused the environment variable with the make variable. I removed that part from the question, and adjusted it accordingly.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, note that usually make variables are initialized from environment variables (look at a reference for the details), but `SHELL` is special in that respect (at least for gnu make), it isn't initialized that way.

Comment: `$SHELL` is the only environment variable that `make` is not allowed to import. This is because users could have a shell like `csh` that is not compatible.

Comment: BTW, rationale of `system` contains "One reviewer suggested that an implementation of system() might want to use an environment variable such as SHELL to determine which command interpreter to use. The supposed implementation would use the default command interpreter if the one specified by the environment variable was not available. This would allow a user, when using an application that prompts for command lines to be processed using system(), to specify a different command interpreter.  Such an implementation is discouraged."

Comment: "... If the alternate command interpreter did not follow the command line syntax specified in the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2008, then changing SHELL would render system() non-conforming. This would affect applications that expected the specified behavior from system(), and since the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2008 does not mention that SHELL affects system(), the application would not know that it needed to unset SHELL."

Comment: I'd not be surprised if the vagueness of the specification is to gather for non Unix Posix implementations (such as those for VMS, Windows, ...) where having the normal command interpreter for the target may be what the user expects.

Comment: Great, helpful quotes. Care to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of the POSIX C APIs use the `SHELL` environment variable explicitly. The [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) and [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) function must call a program called `sh`. A few utilities (e.g. [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html), [`mailx`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html), …) must use `$SHELL`, but always to execute user-supplied code; [`make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) explicitly ignores `$SHELL`.

The section on [environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) allows *utilities*, but not C APIs (“system interfaces”) to have a different behavior if `$SHELL` doesn't comply with POSIX sh.

In practice, `SHELL` is set to the user's login shell, which may or may not be POSIX-compatible. [Zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) and [fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) are popular alternatives. I've been using zsh for a decade on various Unix variants, and I don't remember any system utility failing. I have seen the occasional sloppily written code calling `$SHELL` instead of `sh` to execute sh scripts. This is pretty rare and need not deter you from setting `SHELL` to whatever you like.

In short, yes, `SHELL` is your favorite interactive shell, and applications receive no guarantee of what syntax it accepts, or even whether it accepts a `-c` option.