# checkbashisms-compliant way to determine the current shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, posix, portability

In my `.profile`, I use the following code to ensure that Bash-related aliases and functions are only sourced if the login shell actually *is Bash*:

```
# If the current (login) shell is Bash, then
if [ "${BASH_VERSION:-}" ]; then
  # source ~/.bashrc if it exists.
  if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
  fi
fi
```

I’m currently in the process of putting my shell configuration files, scripts and functions under version control. I’ve also recently started the process of removing casual Bashisms from shell scripts that don’t benefit from Bash-specific features, e.g., replacing `function funcname()` with `funcname()`.

For my shell files repository, I’ve configured a *pre-commit* hook that runs the `checkbashisms` utility from Debian’s [devscripts package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/devscripts) on each `sh` file in the repository to ensure that I don’t inadvertently introduce Bash-specific syntax. However, this raises an error for my `.profile`:

```
possible bashism in .profile line 51 ($BASH_SOMETHING):
if [ "${BASH_VERSION:-}" ]; then
```

I was wondering if there was a way to check which shell is running that wouldn’t trigger a warning in `checkbashisms`.

I checked the list of [shell-related variables listed by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03) in the hope that one of them could used to show the current shell. I’ve also looked at the variables set in an interactive Dash shell but, again, failed to find a suitable candidate.

At the moment, I’ve excluded `.profile` from being processed by `checkbashisms`; it’s a small file so it’s not hard to check it manually.  However, having researched the issue, I’d still like to know if there is a POSIX compliant method to determine which shell is running (or at least a way that doesn’t cause `checkbashisms` to fail).

---

#### Further background/clarification

One of the reasons I’m putting my shell configuration files under version control is to configure my environment on all the systems I currently log in to on a regular basis: Cygwin, Ubuntu and CentOS (both 5 and 7, using Active Directory for user authentication). I most often log on via X Windows / desktop environments and SSH for remote hosts. However, I’d like this to be future proof and have the least reliance on system dependencies and other tools as possible.

I’ve been using `checkbashisms` as a simple, automated sanity check for the syntax of my shell-related files. It’s not a perfect tool, e.g., I’ve already applied a patch to it so that it doesn’t complain about the use of `command -v` in my scripts. While researching, I’ve learned that the program’s actual purpose is to ensure compliance with Debian policy which, as I understand it, is based on POSIX 2004 rather than 2008 (or its 2013 revision).

Comment: What you're doing is as POSIX-compliant as something can be when the whole point is to run differently on different POSIX-compliant environments. Your beef is with checkbashisms.

Comment: And by the way I've never used checkbashisms to check my configuration's portability. I check it by using it on different systems.

Comment: And by the way, for the specific thing you're doing here, write a `.bash_profile` that sources both `.profile` and (conditionally) `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Gilles. That's a very elegant solution for the specific issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your

```
# If the current (login) shell is Bash, then
if [ "${BASH_VERSION:-}" ]; then
  # source ~/.bashrc if it exists.
  if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
  fi
fi
```

code is completely POSIX conformant and the best way to check that you're currently running `bash`. Of course the `$BASH_VERSION` variable is bash-specific, but that's specifically why you're using it! To check that you're running `bash`!

Note that `$BASH_VERSION` will be set whether `bash` is invoked as `bash` or `sh`. Once you've asserted that you're running `bash`, you can use `[ -o posix ]` as an indicator that the shell was invoked as `sh` (though that option is also set when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment or `bash` is called with `-o posix`, or with SHELLOPTS=posix in the environment. But in all those cases, `bash` will behave as if called as `sh`).

---

Another variable you could use instead of `$BASH_VERSION` and that `checkbashism` doesn't seem to complain about unless passed the `-x` option is `$BASH`. That is also specific to `bash` so one you should also be able to use to determine whether you're running `bash` or not.

---

I'd also argue it's not really a proper use of `checkbashisms`. `checkbashisms` is a tool to help you write portable `sh` scripts (as per the `sh` specification in the Debian policy, a superset of POSIX), it helps identify non-standard syntax introduced by people writing scripts on systems where `sh` is a symlink to `bash`.

A `.profile` is interpreted by different shells, many of which are not POSIX compliant. Generally, you don't use `sh` as your login shell, but shells like `zsh`, `fish` or `bash` with more advanced interactive features.

`bash` and `zsh`, when not called as `sh` and when their respective profile session file (`.bash_profile`, `.zprofile`) are not POSIX conformant (especially `zsh`) but still read `.profile`.

So it's not POSIX syntax you want for `.profile` but a syntax that is compatible with POSIX (for `sh`), `bash` and `zsh` if you're ever to use those shells (possibly even Bourne as the Bourne shell also reads `.profile` but is not commonly found on Linux-based systems).

`checkbashisms` would definitely help you find out *bashisms* but may not point out POSIX syntax that is not compatible with `zsh` or `bash`.

Here, if you want to use `bash`-specific code (like the work around of that `bash` bug whereby it doesn't read `~/.bashrc` in interactive login shells), a better approach would be to have `~/.bash_profile` do that (before or after sourcing `~/.profile` where you put your common session initialisations).

Comment: That doesn't pass `checkbashisms` because of the variable used.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, yes but that's a case where the checkbashisms report should be ignored. All the other solutions given so far are considerably worse.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You say that all the other solutions are worse. What would be wrong with using `$0` for this particular case?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan That doesn't distinguish between bash called as `sh` and some other shell called as `sh`.

Comment: It also gives a false positive if `dash` or another non-bash shell was incorrectly called with `argv[0] == "bash"`, which is entirely legal, if unlikely.

Comment: I agree that using `checkbashisms` on `.profile` is not a proper usage and I’d already excluded it from the list of files being checked. However, the additional information has provided more solid reasons why not to do this. For my shell files repository, I’ve already implemented Gilles’ suggestion of having `.bash_profile` source `.profile`.  Finally, I’ve accepted this answer as it not only explains how to determine the current shell in a POSIX compliant way and how to use `checkbashisms`, it provides useful context on writing portable shell (including non-POSIX shells) start-up files.

Answer (score 17):

Usually one uses `$0` for this purpose. On the site which you linked it stands:

```
0
   (Zero.) Expands to the name of the shell or shell script.
```

Comment: So simple! I've become so used to using `$0` for the name of a shell script, that I clean forgot that it can also refer to the current shell. Thanks!

Comment: As usual, this convention is respected by all well behaved programs but a malicious program can mess with you by using various system calls from the `exec` family because they allow the calling program to identify the binary to be run separately from the string to be passed as argument 0.

Comment: That does work for the .profile :) cute

Answer (score 5):

Usually the SHELL environment variable tells you the default shell. You should not need to manually source the .bashrc file (not true see update bellow), bash should do this automatically just make sure it is in the $HOME directory.

The other option is to do something like:

```
 ps -o cmd= $$
```

that will tell you the command (without arguments, the = without a value will not display column headers) of the current process. Example output:

```
 $ps -o cmd= $$
 bash
 $sh
 $ps -o cmd= $$
 sh
```

UPDATE:

I stand corrected! :)

The .bashrc is not always sourced as was mentioned in the comments bellow and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment

So you could move your .bashrc to .bash_profile and see if that works without having to do the test. If not you have the test above.

Comment: `.bashrc` is not actually sourced by a login shell but `.profile` (if it exists) or `.bash_profile` are.  `SHELL` is not specified by POSIX and unfortunately, neither is the `cmd` format option for `ps`.

Comment: This is what I would use, but it is also subject to malicious manipulation.

Comment: Note that while the `ps -o cmd= $$` should work pretty much everywhere, the `$SHELL` variable is completely irrelevant. That is the user's default shell and has no bearing on what shell is currently being run or what shell is running a shell script.

Comment: @terdon, I did mention that.. but you if you are running from your .profile the odds are good your default shell will be running, or is that not a good assumption?

Comment: Not really, no. many shells will read `~/.profile` when started as login shells. So, for example, your `$SHELL` could be `csh` and you run `bash -l`. That will start bash as a login shell, so it will read `~/.profile`, but your `$SHELL` will still point to `csh`. Plus, `.profile` might be sourced explicitly by another script. Since the OP is going for maximum robustness, all sorts of cases should be considered. In any case, `$SHELL` doesn't provide any useful information about the currently running shell.

Comment: FWIW, I too stand corrected – about `SHELL` not being specified by POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03

Comment: Thank you @terdon looks like both learned something new today :).

Comment: @Rob Here's the best resource I've come across for explaining why environmental configuration should be in `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`) and why shell-specific configuration should be in a file such as `.bashrc`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles  Gilles and others have also posted excellent answers to related questions on this site.

Comment: `SHELL` is defined in the 2004 Edition aswell: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Comment: Also, note that `SHELL` is not *guaranteed* to be set. POSIX only defines what happens when it *is* set: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329458/301259 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263773/is-the-shell-environment-variable-only-for-interactive-shells#comment456258_263773

Answer (score 4):

The question asks for the user's *login* shell as well as the *current* shell in a manner that appeases `checkbashisms`.  If that is meant to be the shell on which the user logged in, I would use the one from `/etc/passwd`, e.g.,

```
MY_UID=$(id -u)
MYSHELL=$(awk -F: '$3 == '$MY_UID'{ print $7; }' </etc/passwd )
```

Users can of course start a new shell after logging in.  Of course, if one is bash and the other is not, tests of bash's environment variables may not help.

Some may want to use `getent` rather than just the `passwd` file (but that wouldn't be in the scope of the question).

Based on the comment about LDAP, and the suggestion for [`logname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/logname.html), this alternative form could be used:

```
MY_NAME=$(logname)
MYSHELL=$(getent passwd | awk -F: '$1 ~ /^'$MY_NAME'$/ {print $7;}' )
```

While testing it, I noticed that `logname` does not like its input redirected (so I left the expression split up).  A quick check shows `getent` should work on the platforms mentioned (though that should have been provided in the original question):

- [New package: getent-2.18.90-1](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2014-02/msg00023.html)
- [Authenticate RHEL 5 and 6 SSSD Using Kerberos and LDAP Against Active Directory on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://thornelabs.net/2014/01/30/authenticate-rhel-5-and-6-sssd-using-kerberos-and-ldap-against-active-directory-on-windows-server-2008-r2.html)
- [getent - get entries from administrative database](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/getent.1.html) (Ubuntu)

Comment: Assuming the user database is in /etc/passwd (not LDAP/NIS/mysql...) and that there's only one user name per userid. (would be better to check the first column against `$(logname)`).

Comment: iirc, POSIX doesn't define the utility needed (or I would have used it in my answer).  Whether to use `id` or a user-modifiable variable is a different choice.

Comment: Note that I said `$(logname)`, not `$LOGNAME`. The user id and the login shell are both derived from the username used at login. You cannot get back from the user id to the login shell except on systems where there's only one user name per user id. Or IOW, the primary key in the user database is the username, not the uid.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey for an answer coming from a different perspective. However, it’s a little more complex than what I was thinking of (more like *jimmij*’s and *Stéphane*’s answers). One of the reasons I’m putting my shell configuration files under version control is to configure my environment on all the systems I currently log in to on a regular basis: Cygwin, Ubuntu and CentOS (both 5 and 7, using Active Directory for user authentication). For that reason, I prefer to keep the logic as simple as possible.