# Can't get user $HOME over su on Solaris and AIX

Tags: solaris, aix, su

I'm trying to get user `$HOME` variable over su.

**Solaris**

```
# su oracle
$ echo $HOME
/root
```

**AIX**

```
# su oracle
$ echo $HOME
/
```

**Linux**

```
# su oracle
$ echo $HOME
/home/oracle
```

Can someone explain why on Solaris and AIX when I try to get `$HOME` variable it gets the root's `$HOME` directory?

## UPDATE

Using login with with `-` or `-l` works, but I can't use `su -` on my script. Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

I was trying to not use a solution like the above but I'm getting out of options

`cat /etc/passwd | grep oracle | cut -d: -f 6`

or as Thomas suggested:

`cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '$1 ~ /^'oracle'$/ {print $6;}'`

Comment: Is the oracle user homedir exists on both systems ? If yes try `su - oracle`

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz, yes they exists. And I've tried with `-l`. It doesn't work.

Comment: The double-quotes in the `su -` commands would expand in the current shell (not after `su`).  Using single-quotes would help.

Comment: You are right, just forget about this test. It works, but unfortunetly I can't use su - on the main script because it's ansible code

Comment: Regarding grep, see my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267094/checkbashisms-compliant-way-to-determine-the-current-shell/267192#267192).

Comment: Hi Thomas, I've updated the question with your suggestion. Could you elaborate why the approach it's better? Also, does you know if the position of home directory inside passwd it's the same on all unix distributions?

Comment: On, Solaris, I'd use `getent passwd oracle` to find the right entry in the passwd database, regardless of whether it's in a local file, NIS, or LDAP.

Comment: Nice @alanc I wish I could use this "getent" but this code needs to work on all distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually (quick check) `su` (from a non-privileged user to another non-privileged user) on Solaris does not modify `$HOME` at all.  Perhaps you were **root** when issuing the `su` command.

The Solaris manual page is silent on the matter, but it is a known issue, quoting from a [newsgroup comment](http://www.computing.net/answers/solaris/get-the-home-directory-after-su/5035.html):

```
nails September 16, 2008 at 18:16:45

    jefro:

    Sorry I must disagree wtih you. At least in Solaris su <user id>
    doesn't change the user environment - including environmental
    variables. To change the environment, you must execute
        su - <user id>

    According to the su MAN page:

    If the first argument to su is a dash (-), the environment will
    be changed to what would be expected if the user actually logged
    in as the specified user.
```

However, the manual page says things about several variables, but not `HOME`:

```
   o  In addition to what is already propagated, the LC*  and
      LANG  environment  variables  from the specified user's
      environment are also propagated.

   o  Propagate TZ from the user's environment. If TZ is  not
      found  in  the user's environment, su uses the TZ value
      from    the     TIMEZONE     parameter     found     in
      /etc/default/login.

   o  Set MAIL to /var/mail/new_user.


 If the first argument to su is a dash (-),  the  environment
 will  be changed to what would be expected if the user actu-
 ally  logged  in  as  the  specified  user.  Otherwise,  the
 environment  is  passed  along, with the exception of $PATH,
 which is controlled by PATH and SUPATH in /etc/default/su.
```

That last sentence can be construed to say that the current user's `HOME` variable is passed through without change (unless you use the "`su -`" form, of course).

Other systems:

- The AIX [manual page](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/su.htm) is less helpful, but since the feature is very old in both, the behavior may be based on the same source code.
- HPUX [manual page](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/su.1.html) is also not helpful, saying that "The previously defined **`HOME`** and **`ENV`** environment variables are *removed*."

Because `su` is not giving you the information you need, a different approach would help.  If your accounts all are local accounts (no LDAP), you can always search `/etc/passwd`, e.g.,

```
THATHOME=$( awk -F: '$1 ~ /^'$THATUSER'$/ {print $6;}' </etc/passwd )
```

Notes:

- the format of `/etc/passwd` is the same on all Unix-like systems.
- using `awk` to split up the field into fields avoids the problem with a grep picking up the wrong line (or lines), e.g., if you had an `oracleadmin` account.
- If you had LDAP, you might have the utility `getent` which would allow referring to non-local users.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your help. I've also tried with `su -`, check my last update.

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple, though a common source of misunderstanding.  So common it has a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29):

> **Usage**
>
> When run from the command line, su asks for the target user's
>   password, and if authenticated, grants the operator access to that
>   account and the files and directories that account is permitted to
>   access.
>
> ```
> john@localhost:~$ su jane
> Password:
> jane@localhost:/home/john$ exit
> logout
> john@localhost:~$
> ```
>
> When used with a hyphen (su -) it can be used to start a login shell.
>   **In this mode users can assume the user environment of the target user**:
>
> ```
> john@localhost:~$ su - jane
> Password:
> jane@localhost:~$
> ```

To run a command under a user's environment:

```
su - user -c "command [args]"
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, thanks for your contribution, unfortunately I can't use "su -".   The code who does privilege escalation it's ansible.com, and it use su without login (" -").

Comment: @BernardoVale - So simply write a wrapper script that you start as root with `su`.  Inside the script run `su - username -c "command [args]"`