# What are the environment variables by default?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

When starting a bash shell process, what are the default environment variables, except those specified in the startup file?

Is it correct that some bash or sh builtin variables (listed in the ["Bourne Shell Variables"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html) and ["Bash Variables"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) sections of the Bash manual) are default environment variables while other bash or sh builtin variables are not? What kinds of bash or sh builtin variables are default environment variables?

In [the POSIX definition of environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) it seems that all or most of the builtin variables in bash are environment variables by default, but I am not sure.

Comment: Specifically environment variables and not just shell variables?

Comment: environment variables and not just shell variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A process normally *inherits* envrionment variables from its parent process. Unless programs (e.g. shells) have other conventions, there is no "default" environment variable.

If you are curious, you could use the `env -i` command to clear the environment and use `printenv` to show the environment. Some examples:

```
$ env -i printenv

$ env -i sh -c printenv
PWD=/home/peter
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/printenv

$ echo printenv | env -i sh
PWD=/home/peter
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/printenv

$ env -i sh --login -c printenv
...all kinds of variables from login scripts...
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PWD=/home/peter
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

The bash(1) manual documents some of these variables, but unfortunately it does not provide a definitive answer on whether these *environment* variables are always set or not.

Other variables in bash can be found in a similar way:

```
$ env -i -c set
BASH=/usr/bin/sh
...
BASH_VERSION='4.4.5(1)-release'
...
SHLVL=1
TERM=dumb
UID=1000
_=sh
```

If you need to rely on any of these variables, it is best to check the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/). In particular:

- [5 Shell Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Variables.html)
- [3.7.3 Command Execution Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html)

---

Now given that you have an open bash shell. You would like to know if a certain variable is available to subshells or not. For this, the `declare -p NAME...` builtin can be used to "display the attributes and value of each NAME. Example:

```
$ declare -p PWD
declare -x PWD="/home/peter"
$ declare -p foo
bash: declare: foo: not found
$ foo=bar
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="bar"
```

The `-x` attribute mark a variable as *exported* which means that subprocesses see this variable. To do this for existing variables, you can use the `export` builtin:

```
$ export foo
$ declare -p foo
declare -x foo="bar"
```

In Bash, setting a variable and making it available to subprocesses can be combined:

```
$ export foo=bar
```

Comment: Thanks. How about the question 'Is it correct that some but all the  builtin variables are default environment variables?'

Comment: @Tim I don't know what you mean by "default environment variable", but hope that the addition on exported variables clarifies things a bit.

Comment: I meant that if a shell builtin variable exists i.e. is set in a bash process, must it be an environment variable in the bash process?

Comment: @Tim A variable set in a bash process is not an environment variable. Counter-example: `sh -c 'export foo=bar; grep foo < /proc/self/environ'`. Note that the two terms you use ("builtin variable" and "default environment variable") are not defined. The bash manual puts variables like `PWD` in the category "Variables set by the shell". A "builtin command" on the other hand is defined (e.g., `cd`, `pwd`, `export`, etc.).

Comment: builtin variables https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html.  Default environment variables are environment variables not set by the initialization startup file or by your calls to commands such as `export`. My question is that is a shell builtin variables necessarily be a default environment variable?

Comment: @Tim No, a "shell builtin variable" is not necessary a "default environment variable". For example, `env -i sh -c 'echo "[$PATH]"; printenv PATH'` shows that the variable `PATH` is initialized as variable, but is not available as environment variable. If the latter were the case, then `printenv PATH` should have shown it.