# When and how were these default environment variables created and exported?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Does the following show the default environment variable in a bash shell without running any startup file?

```
$ env -i bash --noprofile --norc
$ export
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PWD="/home/t"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
```

(Note that `set` will give a much longer list of default shell variables which might or might not be environment ones.)

When and how were the three environment variables created and exported?

Who created them, bash itself, or some implicit startup files which I didn't exclude when starting bash?

My question is inspired by [What are the environment variables by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329429/what-are-the-environment-variables-by-default#comment580179_329458)

Thanks.

Comment: They are created by bash itself.

Answer (score 4):

When I'm curious what an open source program is doing, I'll look at the source code (and documentation, and experimentation). Looks like you've found a pretty good list, based on searching for `set_auto_export (` in [bash's source code for variables.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c)

- `$OLDPWD`: 
  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n897
- `$PWD`: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n849
- `$SHLVL`: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n839
- On QNX, `$NODE`: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n483

These are inside `initialize_shell_variables()`, which is [called from](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n1837) `shell_initialize()` in shell.c, which itself is [called from](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n568) `main()` in shell.c.

You can even find [evidence](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n471) of `$PATH` and `$TERM` being marked for export at one point in time, but now `ifdef'd` out.