# Are the environment variables defined by POSIX for a shell, or for any process which doesn't necessarily run shell?

Tags: environment-variables

From APUE

> Some  environment  variables  are deﬁned  by  POSIX.1  in  the  Single  UNIX
>   Speciﬁcation, whereas others are deﬁned only if the XSI option is supported. Figure 7.7
>   lists  the  environment  variables  deﬁned  by  the  Single  UNIX  Speciﬁcation  and  notes
>   which  implementations  support  the  variables. Any  environment  variable  deﬁned  by
>   POSIX.1  is  marked  with  •;  otherwise,  it  is  part  of  the  XSI  option. Many  additional
>   implementation-dependent environment variables are used in the four implementations
>   described in this book. Note that ISO C doesn’t deﬁne any environment variables.
>
> [image]

Are the environment variables defined by POSIX for a shell, or for any process which doesn't necessarily run shell?

Thanks.

My post is inspired from [What are the environment variables by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329429/what-are-the-environment-variables-by-default)

Answer (score 9):

They are *defined* for any process, but they don’t have to *exist* in any process (as a general rule).

[POSIX gives meaning](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) to a number of environment variables. It should be thought of as a dictionary; the fact that a variable is defined in POSIX doesn’t mean that it has to exist (unless its definition says so), but if the variable is present in any process’ environment, its value must be understood (and, for conformant utilities where it is relevant, acted upon) according to the POSIX definition.

> If the variables in the following two sections are present in the environment during the execution of an application or utility, they shall be given the meaning described below. Some are placed into the environment by the implementation at the time the user logs in; all can be added or changed by the user or any ancestor of the current process.

As always “placed into the environment” must be understood as affecting the relevant process tree (children created with the variable set), there is no global environment.