# Why are PAGER, EDITOR, VISUAL empty?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, pager

When I try to use those environment variables, I get an empty string:

```
$ $PAGER some_file;
bash: some_file: command not found
$
```

I tested a few things:

```
$ echo $PAGER;

$ man man;     ## Here it's using less(1)
$ export PAGER;
$ man man;     ## Still using less(1)
$ PAGER='';
$ echo $PAGER;

$ man man;     ## Here it uses cat(1)
$ export PAGER;
$ man man;     ## Here it uses cat(1), too
$ unset PAGER;
$ man man;     ## Here it uses less(1) again
```

Why?  And how can I use those variables?

`env |grep PAGER` shows nothing.

My system is Debian 11 (testing)

---

### Edit:

My intention is to write a script that relies on a pager.

I'd use `less`, but I can't guarantee it'll be present, so I'd like to use `$PAGER`.

Aren't those variables supposed to be always present so that I can rely on them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man` doesn’t *rely* on `PAGER`. On Debian, the tool used to view the output is [determined as follows](https://manpages.debian.org/man-db/man.1#Controlling_formatted_output):

- if the `-P` (or `--pager`) option is set, use that;
- if the `MANPAGER` environment variable is set, use that;
- if the `PAGER` environment variable is set, use that;
- if `pager` exists in the path and is executable, use that;
- otherwise (or if the pager was overridden with an empty value), use `cat`.

`pager` is `less` by default on Debian (see `readlink -f /usr/bin/pager`). The `cat` override won’t apply if the pager is overridden with a non-empty, but non-executable value: `man -P non-existent` will fail with an error.

If you want to set your own value for `PAGER` etc., you can add them to your shell’s startup files; for Bash (the default user shell in Debian), add them to `~/.bashrc`.

The environment variables you mention (`PAGER`, `EDITOR`, `VISUAL`) don’t have to be present in a process’ environment, and you can’t expect them to be. They are useful to allow users to specify their preferences, but you always need a default. Some distributions try to help by providing their own generic commands, for example [`sensible-editor` and `sensible-pager` in Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#editors-and-pagers). See [Are the environment variables defined by POSIX for a shell, or for any process which doesn't necessarily run shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439853/86440) for more discussion of this in general.

Comment: Oh well, I thought there was going to be something like Debian's `pager` that I could use everywhere.  I'll use `pager` since I'm using Debian.  I'll leave the generalization to my future me :p  ...or maybe the future other distros provide `pager` too :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many `man` implementations out there but `man man` from the common
[man-db](http://www.nongnu.org/man-db) project which is also used on
Debian says:

```
   -P pager, --pager=pager
          Specify  which  output pager to use.  By default, man uses less,
          falling back to cat if less is not found or is  not  executable.
          This  option overrides the $MANPAGER environment variable, which
          in turn overrides the $PAGER environment variable.   It  is  not
          used in conjunction with -f or -k.
```

and:

```
  ENVIRONMENT
    (...)
       MANPAGER, PAGER
              If $MANPAGER or $PAGER is set ($MANPAGER is used in preference),
              its value is used as the name of the program used to display the
              manual page.  By default, less is used, falling back to  cat  if
              less is not found or is not executable.
```

So, as you observe `man` uses `less` and `cat` by default if neither
`MANPAGER` nor `PAGER` are set.

Also, notice that in shell you don't need `;` at the end of each line
as in C and that exporting a variable can be done in a single line:

```
export PAGER=''
```

or just set temporarily for a single command:

```
PAGER='' man man
```

Comment: Re ';':  I know; I just like them :)

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable but fall back to a default, use the `${var:-default}` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```bsh
"${PAGER:-less}" "$some_file"
```

To have a cascading list of defaults like man has:

```bsh
myPager=""
for p in "$MANPAGER" "$PAGER" less cat; do
    myPager=$(type -p "$p") && break
done
if [[ -z $myPager ]]; then
    echo "Panic! not even cat can be found!" >&2
    exit 255
fi
```